# For any $x∈E$,there exist an open ball $B(x,\epsilon_x)$ S.T $m_\star(E\cap{B(x,\epsilon_x))}=0$.Prove $m_\star(E)=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given $E\subset{R}^n$,for any $x∈E$,there exist an open ball $B(x,\epsilon_x)$ such that $$m_\star(E\cap{B(x,\epsilon_x))}=0.$$Show that $m_\star(E)=0$.

My proof:

Since $R^n$ is second-countable and $E\subset{R}^n$, $E$ is second-countable as the subspace of $R^n$. Then $E$ has a countable basis for its topology denoted by $B$={$B_i$}$_{i=1}^{+\infty}$,moreover,$E=\cup_{i=1}^{+\infty}B_i$. For any $x∈E$,the intersection $E\cap{B(x,\epsilon_x)}$ is open in $E$.Therefore, there exists a basis element $B_{i_x}$ such that $$x∈B_{i_x}\subset({E\cap{B(x,\epsilon_x)}}).$$By monotonicity, $$m_\star(B_{i_x})\leq{m_\star({E\cap{B(x,\epsilon_x)}})}=0,$$ then $m_\star(B_{i_x})=0$.

Let $\overline{B}=${$B_{i_x}$ :x∈E}.For any $x∈E$,there exist an element  $B_{i_x}$ in $\overline{B}$ such that $x∈B_{i_x}$.Therefore,$E=\cup_{x∈E}B_{i_x}$ .Since $\overline{B}$ is a subset of $B$,it has countable elements.So the element in $\overline{B}$ can be listed one by one denoted by $B_{i_1}$,$B_{i_2}$,$B_{i_3}$,…,$B_{i_n}$,…. And $E=\cup_{k=1}^{+\infty}B_{i_k}$ , $m_\star(E)\leq{\sum{_{k=1}^{+\infty}m_\star(B_{i_k})}}=0$.Hence $m_\star(E)=0$.

Is my proof correct?In my proof,I use the second-countable,can we finish the proof without it?

Comment: You forgot to state that $x \in B_{ik}$. That's important to state.

Comment: Yes,I add it. Is there any other problem?

Comment: I'm not enchanted by your indices. I'd say that for $x \in E$, there's an index $i_x$ such that $x\in B_{i_x}\subset B(x,\epsilon_x)$, and then either directly define $\overline{B} = \{ B_{i_x} : x \in E\}$, or an intermediate index set $I = \{ i_x : x \in E\}$ and $\overline{B} = \{ B_i : i \in I\}$. Apart from that, you misspelled "therefore" twice. But the proof is fine. Regarding the question whether it can be proved without using second-countability, I'm not sure, but I think it can't [unless some other additional condition is given].

Comment: Yes,Thanks for your comment very much!I edited the proof once again.Is the proof more clearly?

Comment: It's fine and clear.